# Антоним к слову "преимущество"

Tags: семантика, антонимы

Нужен подходящий по контексту антоним к слову **преимущество**.

"Недостаток", "уязвимость, "слабость" и подобное не предлагать.
**Недостаток** — это годится для какого-то плана, постоянного качества: "У этого проекта есть один **недостаток**"; **уязвимость** и **слабость** — для какого-то противостояния: "В позиции стороны обвинения есть слабость", "У Черных — уязвимость на ферзевом фланге в виде спаренных пешек" — ну и так далее.

Нужно что-то для другого контекста.

*Ну вот, скажем, пришли пять человек на собеседование. У Ивана — преимущество, он молодой и красивый. А Петр не выспался. У него — **.... [антипреимущество]**.*

*Пример условный, реальный слишком специфичен, ближе к социологии. "Не для здесь".*

Второй час голову ломаю...

(+++)...

Уточняю вопрос в связи с появлением двух или трех комментариев.

По Кузнецову.

ПРЕИМУЩЕСТВО, -а; ср. 1. Качество, свойство, выгодно отличающее кого-, что-л. от других; перевес, превосходство над кем-, чем-л. Иметь явное п. перед кем-л. Показать все преимущества новой машины. Использовать своё п. в численности войск. Получить позиционное, материальное п. в шахматной игре.

Второе значение меня не интересует.

Антоним к нему будет: ***Качество, свойство, невыгодно отличающее кого-, что-л. от других;***

Вот это-то слово, эквивалент этого определения, мне и надобно. Остальное - не очень точно.

(+)----

Еще добавлю. 
Любители шахмат поведали, ***"если у Белых - преимущество, то у Черных - слабость".*** Другие варианты совсем далекие. Похоже, нет слова подходящего даже для единоборства. Хоть самому изобретай этакое "недоимущество".

(+++)

Комментарий от новичка, попавший в ответ, но который жалко просто выбрасывать:

> Можно сказать: если у белых преимущество, то у чёрных изъяны в чем-то
>   и там-то или в тактике игры.

@СусаннаЛанс

Спасибо. В общем-то не так далеко от истины... С той, правда, оговоркой, в шахматах неупотребиетельно, и, конечно, никак не о тактике речь.  "Изъян в тактике" - это что-то очень странное даже на слух.

А применительно к исходному вопросу, об общелитературном антониме... - ну да, отчасти подходит. Но не стопроцентно, все-таки "преимущество" куда более широкое понятие, чем "изъян". Пример с интервью выше - тому пример. "У Ивана - преимущество, у Петра - изъян" - ну никак не годится.

Comment: Тут антоним неуместен. Можно просто дать описание: у него похмелье, у него вчера жена рожала, он вчера тещу встречал и т.д. ))

Comment: Мне нужен антоним. Он или есть - или его нет. "Уместность" как таковая не обсуждается.

Comment: Антоним как таковой НЕДОСТАТОК.

Comment: ... вид конченого трудоголика-профи.

Comment: What about this one: "А Петр не выспался. И оказался в проигрыше." ? : )

Comment: @Anonym спасибо, вариантов, как сказать правильно, может быть  много, но они меня сейчас не интересуют. Интересен именно антоним у слову.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю рассмотреть слово "минус".

У Ивана — преимущество, он молодой и красивый. А Петр не выспался. У него – минус. (Но лучше сказать: "Это его минус.")

Впрочем, я бы предпочел "недостаток", хотя он вам и не по душе. Не вижу проблемы в том, что недостаток временный и относительный.

Comment: Недостаток - не "не по душе", а не по контексту. Минус - антоним ку "плюсу", а не к "преимуществу", плюс и преимущество - очень и очень слабые синонимы. то есть опять-таки имеем очень слабое соответствие.

Answer (score 1):

В текстах часто можно встретить  противопоставления такого вида: **Преимущества и слабости** малого бизнеса. Как превратить свои **слабости в преимущества**?

Типичные антонимы – это сила и слабость (сильные и слабые стороны), но преимущество – это и есть сильная сторона, то есть  перевес и превосходство в чем-то перед кем-то.

Отсюда можно сделать  вывод: слова *преимущество и слабость* используются как антонимы, а **другого антонима скорее всего нет.**

Answer (score 1):

Чистого антонима похоже нет, но можно подобрать синоним к слову "преимущество". *... А Пётр не выспался, предоставив конкурентам фору (гандикап)*.

Comment: Ну да, смысл именно только это привносит элемент соревновательности, даже спортивной состязательности, а это нежелательно.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, что в Вашем случае антонима действительно нет. А ответ на вопрос "почему нет?" находится в области философии: преимущество одного человека по отношению к другому всегда относительно или вообще иллюзорно. Кроме случаев, в которых речь ведётся о чём-то очень конкретном. Тогда характеристики должны быть из одной (сопоставимой) области, а не "один — красивый, а второй — не выспался".

Comment: Вы можете править ответ или оставлять комментарии под своим ответом или вопросом (когда наберёте репутацию, то под ответом или вопросом любого участника). Не нужно давать более одного ответа на один вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

А можно три слова вместо одного? Я предлагаю следующее:

А Пётр не выспался, и это для него препятствие.

"Помеха" тоже бы сработала вместо "препятствия", но вот без "для него" не получается.

Comment: Спасибо. Но тут не совсем по контексту. "Для него" и "у него" - разница не большая, можно и не акцентировать. А вот сами слова "помеха", "препятствие" (особенно первое) - не то. Я уточню вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Качество, свойство, невыгодно отличающее кого-, что-л. от других - **неконкурентность**, неконкурентоспособность. Но это книжное слово, для бытовых ситуаций не подходит.

В бытовой ситуации - неуспешность, незадачливость, но это к Вашему примеру не подходит.

К Вашему примеру трудно найти синоним-слово, только словосочетание - слабость позиции, уязвимость позиции.

А вообще потерять преимущество - потерпеть неудачу,значит, синонимом к этой ситуации будет поражение, неуспех,промах и т.д.

Прямого антонима к слову преимущество нет, по крайней мере, в Викисловаре не решились его написать.

Answer (score 0):

**Сложности** или **затруднения** - вроде по контексту подходит:

> *У Ивана — преимущество, он молодой и красивый. А Петр не выспался. У него — [будут] сложности.*
>
> *Если у Белых - преимущество, то у Черных - сложности.*

Comment: Ну как вам сказать. В шахматном контексте "сложность" применительно ко все позиции - точно не подходит. Там слово употребляется крайне редко и "занято" под несколько другой смысл. Сложность с реализацие конкретного плана - это я еще понимаю. А в позиции вообще - сложность это трудность аналализа. За обе стороны, естественно.

Comment: Ну а в общебытовом контексте - ну очень слабый антоим вы предлагаете. У него не сложности, у него хуже перспективы - по сравнению с другими участниками этого "соревнования".

Comment: @behemothus, ну _бесперспективность_ была бы перебором.

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю вариант - "ущербность"

Answer (score -1):

Если речь идёт о соревновании, тогда "преимущество" означает **шансы на победу.**
Соответственно, антоним — отставание, задержка, пробел, провал.

У Ивана — преимущество, он спал. А Петр не спал. **У него меньше шансов. (Его шансы меньше.)**

Comment: Конкретно можете привести нефантастическую фразу с вашими антонимами? ***"У Ивана - преимущество, у Перта - [отставание]***"? ))))

Comment: Привел. Конкретно. Жирным шрифтом. Но для Вас повторю:
"...у Перта меньше шансов".

Comment: @vbollinger13  *антоним - отставание, задержка, пробел, провал*  Жирным:  *У него меньше шансов*. Вторая попытка.  **Конкретно можете привести нефантастическую фразу с вашими антонимами?**